# pass values in alarm manager

Tags: android

how can we pass the value to receiver...i am using alarm manager...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a `PendingIntent`, whose `Intent` has bundled extras.

This is modified from the [AlarmController Google APIDemo](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmController.java):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmController.this, RepeatingAlarm.class);
intent.putExtra("some_name", some_value);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmController.this,0, intent, 0);

// We want the alarm to go off 30 seconds from now.
long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
firstTime += 15*1000;

// Schedule the alarm!
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,firstTime, 15*1000, sender);
```

Then retrieve those in your Receiver's `onReceive()`:

```
intent.getStringExtra("some_name")
```

Comment: ok i am using alarm manager...it will be scheduled...if the device was rebooted...can the alarm activity correctly process that schedule?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You will need to set a reboot listener, like this: http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/07/permissions-journey-receivebootcomplete.html

Comment: Can I pass more than one value, actually I have to manipulate a record in DB on certain date, I need to pass in the primary ID and one more data item so that it is processed properly.

Comment: @Asral Projection You can add as many extras to the `Intent` that you want using `intent.putExtra("some_name", some_value);`

Comment: i've try doing like this, but my problem is the intent.getStringnExtra just receiving the first intent.. and the second, third intent have the same stringExtra like the first intent.. why is it happened?